# Error when making summary table - Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have tried looking up an answer to this and have been unable to find a solution to my particular code. I am trying to make a summary table including medians and results of a Mann Whitney U. However I get the error:

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

The code I am using is below - this is my first time posting so if I have done something wrong with asking my question I apologise.

Thank you for your help.

```
library("table1")
library("MatchIt")

cog$Type_use <- factor(cog$Type_use, levels=c(0,1,2), 
labels = c("Controls", "Patients", "P-value"))

rndr <- function(x, name, ...) {
    if (length(x) == 0)  {
        y <- cog[[name]]
        s <- rep("", length(render.default(x=y, name=name, ...)))
            if (is.numeric(y)) {
            p <- wilcox.test(y ~ cog$Type_use)$p.value
        } else {
            p <- wilcox.test(table(y ~ cog$Type_use)$p.value)
        }
        s[2] <- sub("&gt;", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001))
        s
    } 
    render.default(x=x, name=name, ...)
    
    }

    rndr.strat <- function(label, n, ...) {
    ifelse(n==0, label, render.strat.default(label, n, ...))
    }

table1(~ cog$Sex_1_USE + cog$Age.at.assessment_two_use  | cog$Type_use, 
data=cog, droplevels=F,  render=rndr, render.strat=rndr.strat, overall=F)
```

Comment: Vinewc, it is difficult to judge from your code. I am also not familiar with the `table1` and `MatchIt` packages. Try to locate which part of your functions in your code throws the error. It feels like that this function uses `unique()` and is supplied with a non-vector object. Check what object is supplied to this function and whether the object is NULL or has another type. There could be something going wrong when this object is created.

Comment: Thanks Ray - have solved by using this code: